# Backing up firefox from old ubuntu version and importing it to new ubuntu installation

Tags: firefox, backup

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04 version. I have a previous version of 10.04. I want to keep all my book marks and history firefox in the new installation. I have read posts here saying to copy `~/.mozilla/firefox` folder from ubuntu 10.04. But how would I then use it in new 14.04 version.

Can anyone explain me step by step process for doing this?

Comment: Just copy paste should work. Also copy `~/.config/firefox` if it exists (it didn't for me). You could also try firefox sync.

Comment: once i copy ~/.config/firefox what should i do in my new installation??

Comment: Well keep firefox closed, copy it to the new install in your home folder and open firefox, that's it

Comment: @Tim : Hi Tim, Everything worked well thanks for the help. Although after installing 14.04 version I also installed gnome-session-fallback as I find that to be better UI than the default UBUNTU in 14.04

Comment: Glad to help :) I use GNOME 3.13 myself. BTW, the default is called Unity :)

Comment: @Tim: Since I am used sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback to go back to gnome, can you tell me how can i find the version of gnome i am using??

Comment: Not sure sorry :( Google didn't have any suggestions either

Comment: I just installed sudo apt-get install gnome-shell and then logged out and signed in as gnome classic option and not fallback. Then i typed in the terminal gnome-shell --version and it showed me GNOME Shell 3.10.4. It would be interesting to know what gnome version fallback has

Comment: Ahh, nice to know thanks :) I'm on Gnome 3.9 it turns out!